# Is it possible to subscribe to JMS queue on Universal Messaging webmethods enterprise server 8.2 using Hermes JMS

Tags: webmethods, hermes-jms

I have found this detail however version 8.2 does not have universal messaging...is there another way of doing it?

http://serviceorientedarchitect.com/how-to-test-jms-processing-in-webmethodsterracotta-universal-messaging-and-integration-server-with-soapui-and-hermesjms/

Answer (score 0):

Universal Messaging supports & provides APIs to connect the Universal Messaging JMS server from different platforms. These can be leveraged to connect from webMethods 8.2 to Universal Messaging JMS servers.

Check below is the link for the details.
[Universal Messaging Developer Guide](http://um.terracotta.org/#page/%2Fum.terracotta.org%2Funiversal-messaging-webhelp%2F_universal_messaging_docset_reverb.1.277.html%23)